# DatabaseException - cannot nest $ under $in (reactivemongo)

Tags: scala, reactivemongo

I need to prepare filters on service A side, and then to use them within service B to query it's DB using those filters.

I'm preparing BSONDocument with filters converting them to JSON (service A):

```
val inQueryForNumericArr(fieldName: String, value: List[BigDecimal]): (String, BSONDocument) =
    fieldName -> BSONDocument("$in" -> value)


val employeeIdQueryBSONDoc: BSONDocument = BSONDocument("employeeId" -> employeeId)
val dateBetweenQuery: (String, BSONDocument) = "date" -> BSONDocument("$gte" -> BSONDocument("$date" -> dateFrom.toEpochMilli), "$lte" -> BSONDocument("$date" -> dateTo.toEpochMilli))


val select:BSONDocument = BSONDocument(List(dateBetweenQuery, {..same format..}) ::: List(inQueryForNumericArr)) ++ employeeIdQueryBSONDoc
```

Then I'm converting "select" to JsValue as:

```
val query = Json.toJson(filters)
case class PayloadFilters(query: JsValue)
```

Then another application(service B) will use this payload to use query data as filter to query it's database:

```
case class FilterQuery(query: JsObject) by the call to getManyByFilter(filterQuery.query)

 def getManyByFilter(selector: JsObject) = {
    collection.find(selector, Option.empty[BSONDocument])
      .cursor[Doc]().collect[List](-1, Cursor.FailOnError[List[Doc]]())
  }
```

On serviceB side I'm getting the following exception:

```
{"@timestamp":"2021-02-21T11:14:19.762Z","@version":"1","message":"fails to send request","logger_name":"reactivemongo.api.Cursor","thread_name":"application-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-18","level":"ERROR","level_value":40000,"stack_trace":"reactivemongo.core.errors.DatabaseException$$anon$1: DatabaseException['cannot nest $ under $in' (code = 2)]\n\tat reactivemongo.core.errors.DatabaseException$.apply(errors.scala:86)\n\tat reactivemongo.core.protocol.ResponseDecoder.failed$1(ResponseDecoder.scala:88)\n\tat reactivemongo.core.protocol.ResponseDecoder.response$1(ResponseDecoder.scala:117)\n\tat reactivemongo.core.protocol.ResponseDecoder.decode(ResponseDecoder.scala:136)\n\tat reactivemongo.core.protocol.ResponseDecoder.decode(ResponseDecoder.scala:17)\n\tat reactivemongo.io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(
```

The query print on serviceA side:

```
PayloadFilters({\"date\":{\"$gte\":{\"$date\":1597104000000},\"$lte\":{\"$date\":1597190399000}},\"nFingers\":{\"$in\":[{\"$numberDecimal\":\"0\"}]},\"employeeId\":\"60022315\"})
```

**Question**
looking for ideas on how to force this type of filter to work?

**Additional Info**

- Service A:

```
"org.reactivemongo" %% "play2-reactivemongo" % "1.0.0-play28"
scalaVersion := "2.13.3"
```

- ServiceB:

```
"org.reactivemongo" % "play2-reactivemongo_2.12" % "0.19.0-play27"
scalaVersion := "2.12.8"
```

P.S
I tried to use implicit serializer (on service A) in order to remove wrapping by $numberDecimal of query, but the final query is not affected by this change.

```
implicit val BSONNumberFormat = new Writes[BSONDouble] {
      override def writes(o: BSONDouble): JsValue = JsNumber(o.toDouble.get)
    }
```

Comment: 1. Mixing different major versions (0.x & 1.x) unsuprisingly lead to complexity.
2. Print `selector` receive by B and check the syntax.

Comment: @cchantep both services sending and receiving exactly the same JsValue                         `{\"date\":{\"$gte\":{\"$date\":1597104000000},\"$lte\":{\"$date\":1597190399000}},\"nFingers\":{\"$in\":[{\"$numberDecimal\":\"0\"}]},\"employeeId\":\"60022315\"}  '                                           I'm looking for a way to send numeric data within the list as $in:[0] instead of $in:[{"$numberDecimal":"0"}]

Comment: You are mismixing [MongoDB JSON extended](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/mongodb-extended-json/) and BSON. `BSONNumberFormat` not only doesn't make sense, but is overcomplex mixing implicit conversion and typeclass.